# Event when finished all nested ngFor loops in angular?

Tags: angular

The nested ngFor loops loading behavior looks ugly. I'am searching a way of displaying both loops only if they are rendered completly.

```
<div *ngFor="let group of bookings$ | async | groupBy: 'date' | pairs; trackBy: trackByFn">
   <ion-item-divider color="light">
     <ion-label text-left>
       {{ group[0] }}
     </ion-label>
   </ion-item-divider>
   <app-booking *ngFor="let booking of group[1]; trackBy: trackByFn" [booking]="booking">
   </app-booking>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the use of ngFor here without some a complex manual workaround which emulates ngFor.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the logic to retrieve data in a resolver - which will get the data the page needs before rendering.

```
export class SomeResolver implements Resolve<any>{
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    return this.yourService.yourMethod().pipe(take(1));
  }
}
```